# RelationsShips Larval 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, relacionamento

Tenho 3 tabelas,[Users -> Departamentos -> Postagems] onde a tabela Users tem muitos Departamentos que Departamentos tem muitas Postagems.

Minha pergunta é: Como faço para relacionar as 3 tabelas com o método with() onde (where()) usuário esta logado seria igual ao id da tabela Users e pegar todas as informações da tabela Departamentos e Postagems?

OBS(tenho os métodos hasMany e também pelo inverso belongstoMany) Mais como eu aplico essa lógica?

Comment: Coloque seus models?

Comment: Se consegiu resolver aqui?

Comment: Sim. Desculpe pela demora ao responder Virgilio. Muito obrigado mesmo pela sua atenção

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não consegui entender muito bem a questão, mas acredito que seu código deveria estar assim:

Users.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

// ignorado...

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ignorado...
    public function departamentos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Departamento::class);
    }
}
```

Departamento.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

// ignorado...

class Departamento extends Model
{
    // ignorado...
    public function postagens()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Postagem::class, 'departamento_id');
    }
}
```

Postagem.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

// ignorado...

class Postagem extends Model
{
        // ignorado...
}
```

Tendo esses 3 arquivos, no seu controller você poderia fazer assim:

```
$departamentos = auth()->user()->departamentos; // departamentos do usuario logado...
$postagens = $departamentos->postagens; // postagens desse departamento...
```

Comment: Então eu tinha todas as minhas relaçoes feitas. No entanto isso aqui que esta pegando . 
tenho o esse método no Departamento
 public function postagems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Postagem::class, 'departamento_id');
    }
Mais quando eu chamo ele no controller ele da erro 
estou tomando assim
$postagem = $departamentos->postagems 
Mais rola um erro Property [postagems] does not exist on this collection instance.
O que sera que esta acontecendo?

Comment: E qual o problema, então? Ainda não consegui captar. :(

Comment: Tipo tudo que vc fez blz , esta certo exeto a parte onde eu chamo o $departamentos->postagens, ai da um erro . 
O que poderia ser? O erro e esse 
Property [postagems] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: No meu Model Departamento tenho o método public funciona postagens
retornando return this->hasMany(Postagem::class);
Mais parece que ele nao chama esse método

Comment: Você fala que o erro é: `Property [postagems]` com M e seu método está setado como `public function postagens()` com N. Verifica isso aí.

Comment: Tudo bem, mais mesmo assim não acessa. mesmo sendo public function psotagens()
e eu chamando $departamentos->postagens; Ele da o mesmo erro. :(
Mais uma coisa que eu não sabia e que podíamos acessar pelo usuário logado método auth()->user()->departamentos
Isso ja valeu por muito. Mais somente falta essa questão ai que não esta chamando no controller.